# When can monothetic groups be turned into rings?

Tags: integers, topological-groups, topological-rings, dense-subspaces

If G is a Hausdorff topological group, saying that G is monothetic is equivalent to saying there exists a homomorphism $f: \mathbb{Z} \to G$ with dense image.

A multiplication can be naturally defined in $f(\mathbb{Z})$ by $f(a) \cdot f(b) := f(ab)$. This forces f to act like a ring homomorphism, therefore turning $f(\mathbb{Z})$ into a ring.

With that in mind, is there any sufficient condition that allows this multiplication to be extended through density to the whole of G? And when is it guaranteed that this extension turns G into a topological ring?
I don't mind assuming G to be locally compact in case that helps.

Comment: That definition doesn't make sense unless $f$ is also assumed to be injective; is that part of the definition of monothetic?

Comment: It's technically fine for f to not be injective. Indeed in that case, its kernel will be a finite index subgroup of the integers, therefore the image will be necessarily a finite cyclic group, and since it is dense, the whole group G has to be finite and cyclic as well. These ones can definitely be turned into rings. The remaining cases are the more interesting monothetic groups.

Comment: In any case, this condition is satisfied by for example any torus $T^n$, using a suitable generalization of the irrational rotation. And none of these have ring structures; in fact any compact topological ring must be profinite.

Comment: Ok, I had no clue about that last statement but that's quite impactful. That means that the only locally compact monothetic groups that can be turned into a ring are the procyclic ones and the integers, right?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't have a clear sense what happens in the locally compact but noncompact case. I do think all the procyclic groups have ring structures, if I understand correctly; they should all be products of copies of the $p$-adic integers together with rings of the form $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Locally compact monothetic groups are either discrete or compact, so the compact case is basically all there is to look at haha